# Change default Qt library names

Tags: qt, qt5.15

I'm building Qt from source codes and would like to give the target libs alternative names. E.g. for example build a lib with a name Qt5Core_my.dll instead of Qt5Core.dll

Does anyone know which part of the script is responsible for the DLL/DYLIB names?

Comment: You might dig in here - qt5/qtbase/lib/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfig.cmake You can download source code [here](https://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git). How to build Qt from source - [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/build-sources.html)